# Why can I no longer bind GradientStop Color to a Dependency Property of my control?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, binding, dependency-properties

The summary of my problem: I had created a `UserControl` where I bound my dependency property "Scheme" to the Color property of a `GradientStop`, and it worked perfectly. Now, after converting my `UserControl` to a custom control, this binding no longer works, and I don't know why.

This is how I declared my resource dictionaries for my UserControl in the `UserControl1.xaml` file.

In `UserControl1.xaml`:

```
<!-- Resources -->
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Within `Colors.xaml`, I have the following:

In `Colors.xaml`:

```
<GradientStopCollection x:Key="colorSchemeGradient">
 <GradientStop Color="{Binding Scheme, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Offset="0"/>
 <GradientStop Color="#000000" Offset="3"/>
</GradientStopCollection>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="colorBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" GradientStops="{DynamicResource colorSchemeGradient}"/>
```

The dependency property Scheme's binding to the color property of the `GradientStop` WORKS Perfectly, exactly how I want it to. The `LinearGradientBrush` uses the Scheme color to create a gradient that goes from the color of scheme to a slightly darker shade of it.

The `UserControl` has a rectangle in it that uses the colorBrush as its background. It all works perfectly, and I love it.

Now, circumstances are making me convert this `UserControl` to a `CustomControl`. I'm doing this by taking the XAML file of my `UserControl` and pretty much copying all its content into `Generic.xaml` in the control template.

After trying different things out, this has seemed to work pretty well for declaring my resource dictionaries in `Generic.xaml`:

In `Generic.xaml`:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">

   <!-- Style Resources -->
   <Style.Resources>

   <!-- Resource Dictionaries -->
   <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyCustomControl;component/themes/Colors.xaml"/>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyCustomControl;component/themes/Styles.xaml"/>
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>

   </Style.Resources>

            .
            .
            .
 </Style>
```

Now, in my `Colors.xaml` file, I have the following:

In `Colors.xaml` for my custom control:

```
<GradientStopCollection x:Key="colorSchemeGradient">
 <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Scheme, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=l:MyCustomControl}}" Offset="0"/>
 <GradientStop Color="#000000" Offset="3"/>
</GradientStopCollection>

<!-- FOR DEBUG PURPOSES -->
<TextBlock x:Key="whoaText" Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=l:MyCustomControl}}"/>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="colorBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" GradientStops="{DynamicResource colorSchemeGradient}"/>
```

Now, for some very frustrating reason I cannot understand, the binding to the `GradientStop` doesn't work anymore. There are no problems in how I have organized my resources, because that debug textblock I made binds to the Title dependency property perfectly.

The `GradientStop` color does not bind to the Scheme dependency property and it is annoying me.

How I can fix it?

In `Dictionary1.xaml` look at the textblock with the `x:key "text2"`. The colorBrush uses gradient stops from `colorSchemeGradient`, which uses a binding to Scheme. However, that binding fails, and so nothing works. If you can get that binding working, you're awesome.

Why does the binding work here and not in the custom control?

Comment: Can you please add a little code, like the XAML for your CustomControl so we can clearly see where the binding fails. {enjoy}

Comment: I edited my post to include a link to a test project for a custom control where the binding doesn't work, and I also included a link to a test user control where the binding DOES work.  What's going on here?  Hope you get a chance to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test project, You seem to have DynamicResources where you need static, and forward references where not required.

In Dictionary1.xaml, change the contents to:

```
<!-- Color Scheme Gradient: Used in the label background and border brush.
                                SUBTLE gradient from the colorScheme color
                                to a slightly darker shade -->
    <GradientStopCollection x:Key="colorSchemeGradient">
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Scheme, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomControl1}}" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#000000" Offset="3"/>
    </GradientStopCollection>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="colorBrush" GradientStops="{StaticResource colorSchemeGradient}"/>

    <TextBlock x:Key="text1" Text="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomControl1}}" Foreground="Blue"/>
    <TextBlock x:Key="text2" Text="This text doesn't show!  Grr..." Foreground="{StaticResource colorBrush}"/>
```

I also changed the text1 and text2 references in Generic.xaml.

Note the `StaticResource` rather than `DynamicResource` in a few places, as well as the reorder to remove forward references.  If you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx , you may note that dynamicresource lookup behavior is a good bit different than static.

Note that switching to static does NOT keep the control from responding to changes to the `Scheme` property - the lookup of the *resources* is static, not the value of properties in those resources.

Comment: I changed all my DynamicResources to StaticResources and it works now, thanks.