# WPF Custom Control: Bind CollectionViewSource to DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `WPF custom Control`, which contains a `ComboBox`. I'd like to bind the `ItemsSource` of this ComboBox to a `Dependency Property` of the custom control class via a `CollectionViewSource`, but I couldn't figure out how to make the CollectionViewSource recognizing the correct `DataContext` (my custom control properties, in this case).

I googled a lot, read almost all SO custom control\CollectionViewSource\Collection binding\dependency properties binding\etc. questions and tried the solutions of some similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3460514/3114639) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415097/3114639) and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14628311/3114639) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11896619/3114639) and it's still not working. I probably miss something, but I don't know what.

Here are the related parts from the Custom Control class:

```
public class CustomComboBox : Control
{
   static CustomComboBox()
   {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomComboBox)));
   }

   public CustomComboBox()
   {
      CustomItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
      DataContext = this;
   }

   internal ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> CustomItems 
   {
      get { return (ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>)GetValue(CustomItemsProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CustomItemsProperty, value); }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CustomItems.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CustomItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>), typeof(CustomComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

   private string text;
   public string Text
   {
       get { return text; }
       set
       {
           text = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Text");
       }
   }

  // More properties, events and functions...

}
```

and the relevant parts of the xaml code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
                    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
                    x:Class="CustomComboBox">

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedData"
                      Source="{Binding Path=CustomItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomComboBox}, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<!-- ...Some more Styles and DataTemplates... -->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                                  Text="{Binding Text}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}">
                                  <!-- ...Some more properties... --> 
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I get this output from `System.Diagnostics`:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : Path:'CustomItems'
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Default mode resolved to OneWay
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Attach to System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.Source (hash=23914501)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): RelativeSource (FindAncestor) requires tree context
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Resolve source deferred
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Resolving source
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Found data context element:  (OK)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Resolving source
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Found data context element:  (OK)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Resolving source  (last chance)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=28932383): Found data context element:  (OK)
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyNamespace.CustomComboBox', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=CustomItems; DataItem=null; target element is 'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=23914501); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')

I tried first this binding:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedData"
                          Source="{Binding CustomItems}">
```

but then I get the error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=CustomItems; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=37908782); target property is
>   'Source' (type 'Object')

BTW- binding inside the ComboBox to another properties works- like the `Text` binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although @KyloRen's answer is generally correct (and the [Inheritance Context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickkramer/2006/08/17/whats-an-inheritance-context/) is particularly useful), I'd like to offer alternative solution. The key point is that the `CollectionViewSource` in question should be defined as a resource of a `FrameworkElement` being a part of the template's visual tree (a good choice in my opinion is the root element). Here's the template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
    <Border (...)>
        <Border.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedData"
                                  Source="{Binding CustomItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                (...)
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Border.Resources>
        <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                  Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}">
            (...)
        </ComboBox>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here are some advantages of this solution:

- It's completely contained within the template, and therefore:

  - changing the template won't leave any unnecessary resources and/or have any impact on the new template
  - it's totally reusable "out-of-the-box", i.e. it doesn't require any additional setup (such as setting properties or adding resources)
- It's `DataContext`-independent, which lets you use it in any data context without breaking the functionality of the control

Note though that for the latter to be true you should modify the bindings within the template to use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` (or use `TemplateBinding` where applicable). Also, I'd recommend removing the `DataContext = this;` line from the constructor, because it would prevent data context inheritance.

Comment: How does DataContext = this; prevent data context inheritance.@Grx70?

Comment: Usual scenario is that you have a `Window` (or a `UserControl`) for which you set some view-model as `DataContext`. You then expect it to be available to all controls you define. In this case though, if you set `DataContext = this`, the `CustomComboBox` (and all of it's visual descendants) will no longer inherit the view-model as data context. This means you won't be able to bind any property to the view-model property without explicitly specifying the source for the binding, or setting `DataContext` to appropriate value.

Comment: Looking at the template of local:CustomComboBox,   I don't think OP wishes to bound any property to ViewModel's property. So he must be doing it intentionally.  But I totally agree with you in general sense that how it would prevent data context inheritance. i was just skeptical in case you meant something else.

Comment: I was rather concerned with binding `CustomComboBox` properties rather than properties of template elements. OP won't be able to bind `CustomItems` property, nor other often bound properties (like `Visibility` or `IsEnabled`) using the "traditional" way.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems in your code and has why have you designed this way? But I'll skip all that part(***you must have some reason to do so*** like setting the `DataContext`, initialization of `CustomItems` etc.) and just edit the `XAML` to make it work. To make your `Binding` work you need to understand the concept of [Inheritance Context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickkramer/2006/08/17/whats-an-inheritance-context/) in `WPF`. Google it you'll find plenty of stuff about it. According to that I've changed your code as below:

```
<local:CustomComboBox>
    <local:CustomComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedData"
                  Source="{Binding Path=CustomItems}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupName" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </local:CustomComboBox.Resources>
    <local:CustomComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomComboBox}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                              Text="{Binding Text}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedData}}">                                    
                            </ComboBox>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </local:CustomComboBox.Style>
</local:CustomComboBox>
```

And it works. Above is not perfect but ***I just made minimal changes***(change structure & binding) to make above code work. Also added `DataSource` as:

```
 public CustomComboBox()
    {
        CustomItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
        CustomItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "4" });
        CustomItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "5" });
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

***Output:***

[image: Custom Combo]

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution here : https://github.com/orhtun/WPFCustomControlBinding

I kept it intentionally very simple, no View Models, GroupedData (as in your example) etc.. If I got your problem wrong, please comment and I will try to fix it :)

Usage is like this;

```
 <wpfCustomControlBinding:CustomControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" CustomItems="{Binding DataStringList}"></wpfCustomControlBinding:CustomControl>
```

[image]