# How can i update the visibility based on the collection count in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

Basically i have two `ListPicker` controls in my Windows phone application. I bind the ListPicker1 using the collection `List<A> ACollection`.

"A" class will be having the another one collection `List<B> BCollection`.

I need the requirement is if `BCollection.Count > 0` then i should enable the Visibility of ListPicker2 and should bind that BCollection[ Its from A class ] to the ListPicker2.

What i expect is , i need to achieve this everything in xaml with 0% c# code in Windows phone.. Is it possible in WP7?

Comment: How are your existing collections bound to the UI? are you using a view-model?

Comment: I am not using ViewModel...But i want to know whether this can be done entirely through XAML

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose `BCollection.Count > 0` condition from your C# model as bool or Visiblity property. So no, it is not possible entirely in XAML w/o C#.

You can write dedicated converter in C# but it would be, well, C# code. See answer by AnthonyWJones for this question [Is it possible to bind to a lambda expression in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510304/is-it-possible-to-bind-to-a-lambda-expression-in-silverlight).